# Excel web part unable to display excel file even after adding library to trusted location

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I added library and site to excel trusted locations in excel services. Under library I set it for both browser and client location to open these excel files and there is no issue with it.

And then I added excel web part to a page and added one of excel file link to it at which it is throwing an error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily fixed. You need to create a trust location for your document library.

Please refer this- http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2011/12/this-workbook-cannot-be-opened-because.html

As the link said: How to add a file to trusted file location:

On the `Start menu`, click `All Programs`.

Point to Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products, and then click `SharePoint 2010 Central Administration`.

On the SharePoint 2010 Central Administration page, under `Application Management`, click `Manage service applications`.

On the `Manage Service Application` page, click `Excel Services Application`.

On the `Manage Excel Services Application` page, click `Trusted File Locations`.

On the `Excel Services Application Trusted File Locations` page, c`lick Add Trusted File Location`.

On the `Excel Services Application` Add Trusted File Location page, in the Address text box, type the location to save your workbook

Under `Location type`, click the appropriate `location type`. In this example, select SharePoint Foundation.

Under `Trust Children`, select `Children trusted if you want to trust child libraries or directories`.

Click `OK`.